# Saving scraped result set into a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, parsing, screen-scraping

I wrote a small script that takes an ebay result set and stores each of the fields in a different variable: link, price, bids.

How can I take the variables and save each result for each auction item into a CSV file where each row represents a different auction item?

Ex: link, price, bid

Here is my code so far:

```
import requests, bs4
import csv
import requests
import pandas as pd
res = requests.get('http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=gerald%20ford%20autograph&rt=nc&LH_Auction=1&_trksid=p2045573.m1684')
res.raise_for_status()
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

# grabs the link, selling price, and # of bids from historical auctions
links = soup.find_all(class_="vip")
prices = soup.find_all("span", "bold bidsold")
bids = soup.find_all("li", "lvformat")
```

Comment: First of all you should think about how to extract the data you need, since e.g. `bids` contains more than the number of bids.

Comment: @albert are you referring to the html text around the bid?

Comment: Yes, and all the other HTML elements around the data which is stored in `links` and `prices`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
import csv
import requests
import bs4

res = requests.get('http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=gerald%20ford%20autograph&rt=nc&LH_Auction=1&_trksid=p2045573.m1684')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

# grab all the links and store its href destinations in a list
links = [e['href'] for e in soup.find_all(class_="vip")]

# grab all the bid spans and split its contents in order to get the number only
bids = [e.span.contents[0].split(' ')[0] for e in soup.find_all("li", "lvformat")]

# grab all the prices and store those in a list
prices = [e.contents[0] for e in soup.find_all("span", "bold bidsold")]

# zip each entry out of the lists we generated before in order to combine the entries
# belonging to each other and write the zipped elements to a list
l = [e for e in zip(links, prices, bids)]

# write each entry of the rowlist `l` to the csv output file
with open('ebay.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    w = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for e in l:
        w.writerow(e)
```

As a result, you'll get a csv-file which as a `,` (comma) as delimiter.

Comment: Thanks Albert for your example

Comment: If I solved your problem, please tick my answer to mark your question as solved.

Comment: do you have any hints as to how I can parse the existing data for the listing title?

Comment: Do you mean as a column title?

Comment: Yes as a separate column I want to put the listing title

Comment: You can do this by specifying so called `fieldnames` and write them to the file prior the data using `writeheader()` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests, bs4
import numpy as np
import requests
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get('http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html? LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=gerald%20ford%20autograph&r        t=nc&LH_Auction=1&_trksid=p2045573.m1684')
res.raise_for_status()
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

# grabs the link, selling price, and # of bids from historical auctions
df = pd.DataFrame()


l = []
p = []
b = []


for links in soup.find_all(class_="vip"):
    l.append(links)

for bids in soup.find_all("li", "lvformat"):
    b.append(bids)

for prices in soup.find_all("span", "bold bidsold"):
    p.append(prices)

x = np.array((l,b,p))
z = x.transpose()
df = pd.DataFrame(z)
df.to_csv('/Users/toasteez/ebay.csv')
```

Comment: What's the need for pandas? Why are you assuming `lxml` parser is installed?

Comment: I just prefer to use numpy and pandas.  Pandas in this instance allowed me to simply write the dataframe to cvs.

Comment: You're definitely right. I prefer those as well. :) However, those provide a somehow large overhead which is not needed in this case.

Comment: I liked this challenge too because I am trying also to learn the Soup.